# Why does the "network" line need to be inside the interface file

Tags: linux, networking

In almost all the network configuration examples I can find, I always see this "network" line appear with an address ending in .0.

```
auto eth0 iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
 -> network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

According to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/580883/what-is-the-network-line-for-inside-the-interface-file), the value can be found by applying the mask to the IP using a logical AND.  If this is the case, why does the line even need to be in the file?  Can I remove it?

Comment: Yes.  This answers my question perfectly.  Thank you.  I searched for an answer before posting my question but didn't find anything...  Likely due to how common the word "network" is.

Comment: I still don't understand why this line needs to be in the network file if it can be obtained simply by applying the mask to the ip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the network address - see the man page here 
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man5/interfaces.5.html

If you know your IP and Netmask you can work out the Network address:

```
IP: 192.168.1.10
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
(Netmask means match first 3 chunks of your IP exactly and any for the last bit)
Network address: 192.168.1.0
```

Usually meaning that devices on your network will have an IP between 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.254
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork

Note: I have used interfaces files on several different Linux flavours and left out Network Address and its worked just fine. If it bothers you that much; backup, remove it and try!